# Nice command without root privileges

Tags: cpu-load, nice

I need to run `dosemu` with `nice --20` from script. Problem is: a negative value can be applied only with sudo.

Do you know any way to run `nice` command without `sudo` or simply run `nice --20 dosemu` from script?

Comment: It's unsecure. It's better to be a root.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I don't think that's easily doable.

If your dosemu process runs as a separate user, then you can set the priority of all processes of that user to a negative value using `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

EDIT: silly me, you *cannot* create a suid shell script, that just doesn't work.

EDIT2: OK, you can configure sudo such that it does not require you to give password when someone from the sudo group runs nice or renice. In a terminal window, enter

```
sudo visudo
```

This will open a simple text editor that will edit the configuration of sudo. Add the following line at the end of the file:

```
%sudo   ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nice,/usr/bin/renice
```

Exit the editor. The editor will make sure that the syntax is correct (otherwise one could break the system). Now, you can run

```
sudo nice -n -20 sudo -u $USER /some/program
```

and you will not get prompted for a password. In fact, nice will start another process called sudo with the -20 priority. This new sudo process will switch back to your original user (`-u $USER`, otherwise you would run the /some/program as root) and starts /some/program.

Comment: This is an old answer, but this advice is just asking for your server to be compromised if a non-trusted user is given access to this command. `nice` runs any command you give it as root!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sudo -k nice -n -20 su -c "dosemu" $USER
```

while it is running, run this:

```
ps -A --forest -o pid,user,command |grep dosemu
```

you will see that `nice` was run with root privileges, but `dosemu` was run as normal $USER.

**Understandind how safe it is**: to make it sure that there is no flaw, try this where you will see it asks the password 2 times because `sudo ls` is run as normal $USER, so a script with sudo on it wont work unseen:

```
sudo -k nice -n -5 su -c "sudo ls" $USER
```

and this will ask password one time only as it is already root to `sudo ls`:

```
sudo -k nice -n -5 su -c "sudo ls" root
```

PS.: instead of dosemu, for tests, I used `sleep 120`, and `sudo -k` is for increased safety.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `sudo -s -H`

It logs you in as root after which you won't need the sudo.

Then run your script.